# Microsoft CA - how to add SAN during certificate request

Tags: .net, powershell, ssl-certificate

I am currently using the following to submit a CSR to the domain CA and save the resultant certificate:

```
    $RequestFile = 'c:\temp\mycsr.csr'
    $IssuingCA = 'MyCA.fqdn.local/MyCAInstance'
# Use CSR path for output file location
    $SavePath = (Join-Path -Path ([system.io.fileinfo]$RequestFile).DirectoryName -ChildPath ([system.io.fileinfo]$RequestFile).BaseName) + ".cer"

# Submit request
    $CertRequest = New-Object -ComObject CertificateAuthority.Request
    $RequestData = [IO.File]::ReadAllText((Resolve-Path -Path $RequestFile -ErrorAction Stop).Path)

# Specify template
    $Attributes = "CertificateTemplate:WEbServerTemplateV3"
# Submit request
    $Status = $CertRequest.Submit(0xff,$RequestData,$Attributes,$IssuingCA)
# Export certificate object to file
    $base64 = $CertRequest.GetCertificate(1)
    $NewCertificate = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 (,[Convert]::FromBase64String($base64)) -ErrorAction Stop
    Export-Certificate -FilePath $SavePath -Cert $NewCertificate -ErrorAction Stop
```

I'd like to have the option to add a SAN to the request during this process (I have Enrollment Agent rights to do this). I know this can be done using the **certreq** utlity and an inf file to amend the CSR before submission as follows:

`certreq -policy -config CAserver/CAInstance PathToCSR.csr InfFilewithSANsettings.inf PathToNewCSRFile.csr`

Inf file example

```
[Extensions]
2.5.29.17 = {"text"}
_continue_ = {dns="san1.fqdn"&"}
```

I'd like to avoid using certreq, so any idea on how certreq is performing this operation and to code this without it?

Comment: If you really want to do it manually, you will have to familiarize yourself with the [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) format, which is used to encode the information of a CSR. I highly recommend to use existing libraries instead, like `CertReq.exe` or `openssl`. Otherwise you risk to reinvent the wheel...